# Migrate MS Access DB to SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: sql-server-ce, data-migration, ms-access-2003

I have a MS Access DB and I need to migrate it to SQL Server Compact Edition. Is there any migration tool for doing it? I need to migrate DB structure and data. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tools from www.primeworks-mobile.com should be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, there are many paid application but I need a freeware solution. Thanks anyway. BTW, the process should be automatic and transparent for the user at the time of upgrade.